# Why can't you have an isoceles trapezoid with sides $\{1,1,3,5\}$?

Tags: geometry

I was recently solving a problem in Google's Code-jam and it mentioned in one of the test cases that you can not have an isosceles trapezoid with sides $\{1,1,3,5\}$. I tried drawing it and I don't see why this statement holds? Are there sufficient conditions for the 4 sides to be able to say they can form an isosceles trapezoid?

Comment: it is not true, it is a trapezoid or not depending on the definition. if all sides can be on one line then yes it trapezoid, obviously they have defined the trapezoid to not be on  one line, it is their choice of definition, you can very well start your own code-jam and have that test case to be true. There is no deep reasoning. did the have a test case for 0, 0, 0,0 as well? :)

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*: Try to calculate its altitude.

Comment: Ohh wow, I totally missed that! I was drawing a trapezoid with bases 5 and 3 and sides 1 but I forgot that it would actually be a line because 1+1+3=5!! Thank you!

Comment: @AspiringMat : where did it say the height of trapezoid must be more than 0?

Answer (score 1):

> sufficient conditions for the 4 sides to be able to say they can form an isosceles trapezoid

Let $a \le b$ be the parallel bases and $c$ the equal sides. The necessary and sufficient condition for a non-degenerate isosceles trapezoid to exist with those side length is $\,b \lt a + 2c\,$.

The given case $\,b=a+2c\,$ corresponds to a degenerate trapezoid with all points collinear.

Comment: "degenerate isosceles trapezoid" according to who? where is definition for such a thing? would 0,0,0,0 be  a non-degenerate isosceles trapezoid ?

Comment: @Arjang See ["degenerate triangle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)#Triangle) and "degenerate convex polygon" on the same page.